# Multiple Rows INSERT in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'am trying to add multiple rows into DB using SQL and it goes wrong with a message

*"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''imglist' ('urlImg', 'idProduct') VALUES('C//','1')('C//','1')('C//','1')('C//','1')' at line 1"*

**This is my code for this function**

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO \'imgList\' (\'urlImg\', \'idProduct\') VALUES';

for($i=0;$i<10;$i++){

$sql .= '(\'' . $_POST['urlImg'][$i] . '\',\'' 

              . $_POST['idProduct'][$i] .'\')';

                if ($i<count($_POST['urlImg']) - 1) {
                   $sql .= ',';
                }
}
```

Comment: NEVER put a variable that comes from the user into the sql query directly. You may get injected. Use mysqli_real_escape_string function and can you provide the produced sql query and your table structure?

Comment: Just use a prepared statement instead of making queries by concatenating strings. Gets rid of quoting issues which also have nasty security implications.

Comment: Thanks Firat Akandere & pvg, but this is for admin panel, i create a slide show of each product for admin when they add new product and slide show together. I don't know what 's wrong with my sql query. Do you know or give me some solutions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, first of all, like others said, never concatenate values into SQL string directly. Not only it puts you at risk of SQL injection, but also will fail if you have single quotes in your data.

If query you built fails, then output it using echo and examine it. That error you're seeing is because you put single quotes (') around your table and column names, which is wrong. You should either use backticks (`) or don't use anything - quotes are only for literal strings.

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO `imgList` (`urlImg`, `idProduct`) VALUES ';
```

There are other problems with your code, though. `for($i=0;$i<10;$i++){` will loop 10 times even if you only have 1 element in `$_POST['urlImg']`, resulting in errors. And judging by `VALUES('C//','1')('C//','1')('C//','1')('C//','1')` in error, this part of code:

```
if ($i<count($_POST['urlImg']) - 1) {
                   $sql .= ',';
                }
```

doesn't even work properly, since commas aren't even inserted between `(...)`. No idea why, though, it worked fine when I tried it myself, perhaps you didn't show something.